# Merge field not populated in the subject of a Text Email Template

Tags: email, email-template, merge-field

I am facing the following issue:

I have specified an email template that points to an Account record. I have included in the body and the Subject both, merge fields.

The values in the body of the email template appear to be populated without any obstacle, but the problems is that this doesn't happen too with the subject.

In fact, my subject outputs with the whole mergefield configuration, without interpreting it at all.

*The configurations, looks something like:

Subject(Email Template): Dear Mr. `{!Account.Fancy_Name__c}`

While, in the subject of the actual email that I want to send, I have exactly: "Dear Mr. `{!Account.Fancy_Name__c}`"*

Thanks in advance guys!

Cheers,
Endrit.

Comment: is it vf template or html template?

Comment: It is a simple Text Template.

Comment: @EndritSino are you using single.messaging. If yes pls add your singleMessaging code

Comment: is email generated from apex or via email alert?

Comment: Did you type the merge field, I thought I remember someone running into this issue and when copying and pasting the merge field instead it magically working.

Comment: @Ratan: Yes, actually I am simulating the sending of an email, to leverage the use of the email template, to visualize specific data of a record, but why that should make a difference?
@ crop1645: Yes, the email is generated via Apex.
@ JennyB: Please, give me further dettails of what you mean, because I am not understanding.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment, if you are using the custom email template, where it has dropdowns under available merge fields. Copy and paste the merge field value instead of manually typing it in the subject. I know it shouldn't matter but for whatever reason I thought someone once resolved a similar issue that way.